# XML for jqgrid doesn't bind

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the following xml format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<return>
<actions>
<action>
<ActionId>102</ActionId>
<PatientId>1234</PatientId>
<Priority>0</Priority>
<Recurrence>0</Recurrence>
<PtName>name, patient</PtName>
<ActionStatus>Not Started</ActionStatus>
<DueDate>05/04/2012</DueDate>
<AssignedTo>lname, assigned</AssignedTo>
<FacilityName>facility abc</FacilityName>
<CreatedBy>created by abc</CreatedBy>
<StartDate>05/04/2012</StartDate>
<Subject>General -</Subject>
<ActionType>test action</ActionType>
</action>
<action>....</action>
</actions><Total>3</Total></return>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My jqgrid code is:

```
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'xmlstring',
        datastr : stringXML,
        colNames:['ActionId','PatientId', 'Priority','Recurrence','PtName','ActionStatus','DueDate','AssignedTo','FacilityName','CreatedBy','StartDate','Subject','ActionType'],
        colModel :[ 
          {name:'ActionId', index:'ActionId', width:55 }, 
          {name:'PatientId', index:'PatientId', width:90}, 
          {name:'Priority', index:'Priority', width:80}, 
          {name:'Recurrence', index:'Recurrence', width:80}, 
          {name:'PtName', index:'PtName', width:80 }, 
          {name:'ActionStatus', index:'ActionStatus', width:80}, 
          {name:'DueDate', index:'DueDate', width:80}, 
          {name:'AssignedTo', index:'AssignedTo', width:80}, 
          {name:'FacilityName', index:'FacilityName', width:80}, 
          {name:'CreatedBy', index:'CreatedBy', width:80},
          {name:'StartDate', index:'StartDate', width:80},
          {name:'Subject', index:'Subject', width:80},
          {name:'ActionType', index:'ActionType', width:80},
           ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:10,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'My first grid'
      }).navGrid('#pager1',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});        
}
```

However, its not able to bind it. I have put the xml into  a variable stringXML:

> var stringXML = "abovexml";

I get an error in my IE debugger : 
**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference 
jquery.jqGrid.min.js, line 130 character 62**

Really frustrated, I have tried editing my xml : Deleting the soap tags, but it doesn't work. I don't want to put an overhead of converting it to json and then binding it. However that doesn't work too.

Comment: The " can be replaced by ' quotes. But no use of that too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to define an xml Reader that can parse your XML data, along the lines of:

```
xmlReader: { 
   root:"return", 
   row:"actions",
   cell:"action"
}
```

See [the jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#xml_string) for more information.

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It still shows me an error in the IE console stating: 'Line: 132
Error: Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference'                                                                           and populates : data1, data2, data3, data4, data5

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?